# Browserify ReactJS Invariant Error

Tags: reactjs, browserify

I'm using ReactJS with Browserify and I'm getting the following error when `require`ing the same module in multiple files... which is kind of the point of Browserify, isn't it?

**Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: mountComponent(.0.1.0.0.0, ...): Can only mount an unmounted component. Make sure to avoid storing components between renders or reusing a single component instance in multiple places.**

My components is declared as:

```
var React = require('react');

var Toolbar = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div />
    );
  }

});

module.exports = Toolbar;
```

Then in both `View1` and `View2` I require the component with:

```
var React = require('react');
var Toolbar = require('./Toolbar.jsx');

var ViewN = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <Toolbar/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = ViewN;
```

Am I structuring this incorrectly?

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else in your code.  Possibly where you call `React.mountComponent`.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand You're right! Again. It turns out this is related to my question about embedding SVG that you answered. I was storing the SVG markup in a variable, then trying to reuse that variable in my component; `return <span>{SVGs.someSVG}</span>`. React, it seems, was mounting that SVG as a component and the error was happening when I tried to use the same `.someSVG` more than once. I've wrapped each SVG in its own component, so now I'm `return <span>{SVGs.someSVG(null)}</span>`. This seems a bit inefficient as I have to render a new component just to get some SVG markup, but it works.